# Is there a neater way to convert a xlsx object to csv in Ruby using the podio gem

Tags: ruby, file, csv, io, podio

I'm working with the Podio application, and I made a tiny little script to grab data from my Podio database and put in an xlsx file, and convert it to a csv using roo.

```
xlsx = Podio::Item.xlsx( <app_number>, options = {} )

fname = "blah.xlsx"

somefile = File.open(fname, "w")
somefile.puts xlsx
somefile.close
xlsx_data = Roo:Spreadsheet.open(fname)
csv = xlsx_data.to_csv
puts csv
```

So this works, but printing to a file, only to grab the data back again and convert it to a csv seems...sloppy.  Is there a way to not print it to a file, put it in a variable, and then convert it to a csv so I'm not printing files?

I tried using StringIO.new to the output from Podio::Item.xlsx, but I got this as a response:

```
file = StringIO.new(xlsx)

`extname': no implicit conversion of StringIO into String (TypeError)
```

Didn't see anything about this in the Podio docs: https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-items-as-xlsx-63233 It just mentioned how to export an xlsx file, not what to do with it afterwards.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Roo::Excelx` fakes support of streams by [creating temporary file](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo/blob/master/lib/roo/excelx.rb#L45). So you won’t gain any profit avoiding it and passing `StringIO` instance to it.

I was unable to receive the error you received, but stream support in `Roo` is kinda cumbersome and I failed to load a stream directly, yielding it from:

```
StreamIO.new(File.read('/tmp/my_xlsx.xlsx'))
```

In your case I would go with [`Tempfile`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) instance, just for the sake of code readability.